# Template marketing cloud: I would like to unlock full html, so that I can personnalize my template with class and tables

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, html-area-component, html-template-directives

I used a marketing cloud template and I want to customize it with extra html (to make it render well on a specific email client). The thing is that  when I click on code view > toggle 'show full html'> a lot of the code is locked (yellow area).

How can I unlock it?

Answer (score 2):

You don't. Marketing Cloud templates are locked for a reason - so that people not comfortable with HTML wouldn't be able to mess them up.

What you can do is copy the code and create a new, HTML-paste type of a Email and paste it there. This way you will be able to modify everything in the fresh code paste.

This is covered in the [**January 2018 release notes**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_january_2018_content_builder.htm&type=5).

> **Show Full HTML Option**
>
> When editing a template-based email or the HTML for a template, there is a new option to see the full, compiled HTML. 
>   You no longer need to send a test of a template-based email or edit an
>   individual content block to view the source HTML.
>
> When selected, the full HTML of the email is displayed in a view-only
>   pane on the left. A lock icon indicates that you can’t edit the HTML.
>
> When editing template HTML, a new option at the bottom of the HTML
>   editor lets you toggle to the “full” view of the HTML. You can’t edit
>   HTML in this view, and block HTML is highlighted.

Comment: I tried above but not able to see blocks in editor and drag n drop features in HTML paste template?

Comment: It looks like a recent release prevents copying the HTML that is visible when viewing the code for a template... really really frustrating